# FactoryGirl Rails Argument error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am having a weird problem / error with FactoryGirl on Rails:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
  /Users/bintoy/ruby-apps/tradegecko-exercise/exercise-app/spec/factories/object_records.rb:3:in `object_id'
```

Note: This is not a duplicate question from this: [Why am I getting FactoryGirl wrong number of arguments error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732450/why-am-i-getting-factorygirl-wrong-number-of-arguments-error) - Also I already tried a lot of possible solutions like manually loading or noticing the problem with FactoryGirls and Spring. But none of them worked.

The setup is that the database is based on MongoDB (Mongoid mapper) and here are the involved files:

app/models/object_record.rb

```
class ObjectRecord
  include Mongoid::Document

  validates_presence_of :object_id, :object_type, :timestamp, :object_changes
  validates_uniqueness_of :timestamp, :scope => [:object_id, :object_type]

  field :object_id, type: Integer
  field :object_type, type: String
  field :timestamp, type: DateTime
  field :object_changes, type: Hash

end
```

spec/features/user_searches_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

    feature 'User searches on table' do
      before :each do
        FactoryGirl.create(:object_record)
      end

      scenario 'with an object id', js: true do
        input_a_search '1'

        expect(page).to have_css(".sorting_1", :text => "1")
        save_and_open_screenshot

      end

      def input_a_search(search_word)
        visit object_records_index_path
        find('input[type=search]').set(search_word)
      end
    end
```

spec/factories/object_records.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :obect_record do
        object_id   1
        object_type "ObjectA"
        timestamp 1465748715
        object_changes ({:property1 => "val1"})
    end
end
```

spec/support/factory_girl.rb

```
    RSpec.configure do |config|
      config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
    end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.after(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    FactoryGirl.reload
  end


  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|

    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|

    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

end
```

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'

require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist

require 'factory_girl_rails'


Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

end
```

EDIT:
Out of just a random trying to debug this, I tried omitting the argument for object_id in the factory to see what happens:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :obect_record do
        object_id   
...
```

But instead I got this Failure/Error message from Rspec:

```
  1) User searches on table with an object id
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:object_record)

     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: object_record
     # ./spec/features/user_searches_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an existing [`object_id`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-object_id) method in ruby: your factory is calling that method, rather than falling through to the `method_missing` code in factory girl that creates an attribute.

The method missing hook is just a convenience, you can add attributes directly by calling

```
add_attribute :object_id, 1
```

In addition your factory definition appears to have a typo (`obect_record`).

Because `object_id` is a core ruby method, it's not impossible that you'll run into other issues as a result of using that name.

Comment: Dude, you rock! Thanks! I'll take a not of this. Solved the problem using all of your inputs.